# Best replacement for IVY in IRAD 7

Tags: java, ivy, ibm-rad

IVY doesn't seem to be supported in IRAD 7. I wanted to move away from this. Any advice?

Comment: You need to supply more details. Ivy is a plug-in for ANT. Surely IBM's Rational Application Developer (IRAD 7) supports a java build using ANT?

Answer (score 1):

The more recent IvyDE plugins that use IVY 2.0.0+ do not work in IRAD.  IRAD uses an older version of jsch - resulting method not found exceptions when ivy tries to retrieve artifacts.  Downgrade to an older version of the plugin.

Or even better, stop using IRAD and install Eclipse.